# How can I change the background of my panels in Flash Develop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I used a theme to change the colors of my code and background, but all the other panels are still white on background. I would like to set a dark background on all my panels/windows, is that possible?

[image]

PS.: I tagged this as *actionscript* just to give a little more visibility, as *flashdevelop* tag have lesser popularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the Tools menu, there you should be able to set the colors of the GUI.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you that **should** be a way to change that, but I created this question just because I didn't found any way. :)

Comment: Alright, I read on some resource that there were a setting like that. Apparently it was wrong.

Comment: I'll assume that's not possible. But I'll give you the correct flag anyway, due the fact you were the only one who came to answer.